# pairs of intersecting chords

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we are given a convex $n$-gon and all possible pairs of non adjacent vertices are joined to form chords. Let $f(n)$ be the number of pairs of intersecting chords. So $f(4)=1,f(5)=5$. I want to determine $f(n)$ in general.

Some thoughts:

> Its not clear to me as to why $f(n)$ is well defined.
>
> $f(n)=f(n-1)+$ something. I want to determine that something.
>
> Is $f(n)$ an upper bound for the crossing number of $K_n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andre's solution shows you how to do this directly.

If you want to approach it using your method of $f(n) = f(n-1) +$ something, then observe that when we introduce the additional vertex $V$, any new point of intersection must involve this vertex $V$.

Any point of intersection will have to involve 3 vertices from the other $n-1$. It is clear that given any set of 3 vertices, there is a unique point of intersection, obtained by adjoining $V$ to the 'middle' vertex. Hence "something" $= { n -1 \choose 3}$.

You can now solve the recurrence to show that $f(n) = {n \choose 4} $.

Answer (score 1):

We need to assume the vertices are in "general position."

Take any $4$ vertices. One pair of chords determined by these vertices meets inside the polygon, the other two do not. So the number of chord intersections inside the polygon is $\binom{n}{4}$.